# Data format in comparison

Tags: python, python-2.7

Please can someone explain to me why `cmd` and `req` are considered unequal? Also, how can I make them equal?

```
cmd = 0x10
test1 = '\x10'
req = test1[0]
if(cmd is req):
    print "Equal"
else:
    print "Not Equal"
```

I am using `python 2.7`.

Comment: Never use `is` for equality testing, only identity testing.

Comment: @trentcl Suggested an edit

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`cmd` is an integer. `req` is a string. The two are not equivalent so your code prints "Not Equal".

You could do this instead:

```
if chr(cmd) == test1[0]:
    print "Equal"
else:
    print "Not Equal"
```

[`chr()`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#chr) converts an integer in the range 0-255 to the single byte string corresponding to the integer.

Also, use `==` to test for equality, not `is`.

You could write this more simply:

```
print "Equal" if chr(cmd) == test1[0] else "Not Equal"
```

---

For completeness, you could instead convert `test1[0]` to an integer using [`ord()`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#ord), which is the inverse of `chr()`:

```
print "Equal" if cmd == ord(test1[0]) else "Not Equal"
```

Answer (score 1):

The keyword `is` does not test equality. It tests identity. If you want to check if the strings are equal, just use `==`.

In this case, you also need to convert the integer to a string first.

`a is b` is the same as `id(a) == id(b)`, and from the documentation of id():

> Return the “identity” of an object. This is an integer (or long integer) which is guaranteed to be unique and constant for this object during its lifetime. Two objects with non-overlapping lifetimes may have the same id() value.
>
> CPython implementation detail: This is the address of the object in
> memory.